# Including Templated C++ in Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, templates

I am trying to include a C++ library with quite a few templates into an objective C application.

It seems to perpetually choke on a few inline statements inside a shared library:

```
template <class T>
inline T MIN(T a, T b) { return a > b ? b : a; }

template <class T>
inline T MAX(T a, T b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

yielding the output:

```
expected unqualified-id before '{' token
expected `)' before '{' token
```

I am compiling with the options.

```
g++ -x objective-c++ -Wall -O3 -I. -c demod_gui.m -o demod_gui
```

All the other templates seem to compile fine, any idea what could be wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the shared library define its own min & max functions? These are included in `<algorithm>`

Comment: Now that I mention it, `MIN` and `MAX` might be `#defined` in one of the objc++ headers. If that's the case, then it's probably trashing your template definitions.

Comment: That answer wasn't there when i commented! I swear! -_-

Comment: Thats was exactly the problem, added a `#ifndef __OBJC__` to fix the shared library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are already macros `MIN` and `MAX` defined in `Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h`.

```
#if !defined(MIN)
    #define MIN(A,B)    ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __a : __b; })
#endif

#if !defined(MAX)
    #define MAX(A,B)    ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; })
#endif
```

So your definition becomes

```
template <class T>
inline T ({ __typeof__(T a) __a = (T a); __typeof__(T b) __b = (T b); __a < __b ? __a : __b; }) { return a > b ? b : a; }
```

which is obviously invalid.

Why not use [`std::max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) and `std::min`?